# File upload to Amazon S3 from PHP

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload a big file (around 1.8GB) to amazon s3 using their php api.

Somehow, upload fails. I have added lines to increase timeout, so I don't think it should be an issue.

What I get is "Resource id #20" everytime.

I tried uploading small files and that worked fine.

I am executing this script from a shared server, could it be due to resource limitation?

Please help me solve this.

Comment: "Resource id #20" means that you're trying to `echo` the variable that contains some sort of resource (in your case perhaps it is handler to curl).

Comment: It's very, very unlikely that a shared server can handle uploading a 1.8GB file using PHP.

Comment: overriding the max execution time in your local file, or even in a local php.ini doesn't necessarily have any effect in a shared hosting environment, as your host may have those disabled.

Comment: @Mihir, could you please share the php code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the multipart/large file upload support. See the [rest api](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?mpUploadInitiate.html) or its easier if you use the [php sdk](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/initiate_multipart_upload)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a signed integer Problem by uploading files larger than 2GB - see here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27792

Comment: I know about that but file is less than 2 GB. I get fopen error if file is bigger than 2 GB. So it's not the issue in this case.